# Where are the terminal preferences saved in Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, settings, xfce4-terminal, preferences

I have a cluster of machines all running the same OS: Xubuntu 20.04.  I usually change the terminal settings a lot, and I'd like them to all be the same across devices and usernames.

I can't find the settings in any file.  I've tried changing them and using 'find -newer ' but I don't see any file that got changed.  I've looked in gsettings, but the only schema whose name includes "term" just knows how to start it up, not how it's configured.

So where are the "preferences" of terminal-emulator in xfce4?  I'd like to copy them.

Answer (score 1):

`$HOME/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc`

Comment: That works for my users. But the /root directory only goes as far as /root/.config/xfce4/ -- there is no terminal/terminalrc there. But root terminals are also configured on my machines.